# show button in specific list item- react - antd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

I have a list of items. I want to display the delete button when the user hovers on a specific item.

I am using React with and ant typescript.

I tried this code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import styles from './App.module.scss';
import { List, Button } from 'antd';
import { getCasesList } from '../../services/AuthService';
import { ReactComponent as Delete } from '../../assets/svg/deleteDraft.svg';
import { Message } from '../../interfaces/Message';

 const App = () => {

  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<Message[]>([]);
  const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
getCasesList()
  .then((res) => {
    setMessages(res.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
  });
 }, []);

const deleteMsg = (e: any) => {
console.log("clicked!!!", e);
}

return (
<>
  <List
    className={styles['list']}
    dataSource={messages}
    renderItem={(item: Message) => (
      <List.Item
        onMouseEnter={() => setIsShown(true)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setIsShown(false)}>
        <h1> hi {item.title}</h1>
        {isShown && (
          <Button className={styles['delete-btn']} icon={<Delete />} onClick={(e) => deleteMsg(e)} />
          )}
      </List.Item>
    )}
  />
</>
);
};
export default App;
```

what I got from this code is displaying (all) items buttons not only the hovered one, using "onMouseEnter".  is there any way to display the button of only the hover item using the list component?

any suggestions would be helpful, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with some simple CSS and the `:hover` selector.

```js
const Item = props => {
  return (
    <div className="item">
      Item number {props.num}
      <button>Delete {props.num}</button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.Fragment>
    <Item num={1} />
    <Item num={2} />
    <Item num={3} />
    <Item num={4} />
  </React.Fragment>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
button {
  display: none;
}

.item:hover button {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```